# Using jmeter, how to download an image file that is inside the modal?

Tags: css, jmeter, css-selectors

I am trying trying to test to download an image file using Jmeter. The image is inside the pop-up/modal? How can I do it?

For example in the below page:

https://www.analog.com/en/products/ad7607.html

I  need to click the magnifying icon to zoom the image. ANd inside the modal, there is an "download" icon which I need to test  using Jmeter.

Can someone help how can I do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you tried using JMeter for this Problem Statement?

Answer (score 1):

Image location on the WebApp is not an issue when working with Jmeter. But figuring out actual API call web application make in back-end is important.Since with JMeter we need to actually replicate the back-end call.

Steps to download image:

Do a GET request to [URL](https://www.analog.com/-/media/analog/en/products/image/functional-block-diagrams/ad7607-fbl.png?h=270&hash=791E966071B1BD8B9C2DAB9DECF4F62C68E2D7E6) from Jmeter,and add "Save Responses to a file" Jmeter listener as child of the request. JMeter will download the file to JMeter_Home/bin folder. [Refer per further details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45095839/test-download-a-file-using-jmeter-the-http-response-has-download-link)

https://www.analog.com/-/media/analog/en/products/image/functional-block-diagrams/ad7607-fbl.png?h=270&hash=791E966071B1BD8B9C2DAB9DECF4F62C68E2D7E6